# how to validate, to enter negative and positive decimal values upto 2 decimal places using jquery keypress

Tags: jquery

I have a grid in which i have to allow user to enter either positive or negative value upto 2 decimal places.

```js
                
//On keypress event
              amountValidation: function (e) {

                    $('.js-amt').keypress(function (e) {
                        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
                        var newValue = this.value + character;
                        if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
                        pointIndex = value.indexOf('.');
                        return pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
                    }                   

                        
                    
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 $('.js-amt').keypress(function (e) {
   var regex = /^-?\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;
   if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
     this.value = '';
}});
```

You can also  use:

```
 $('.js-amt').keypress(function (e) {
   $(this).val(function(i,val){ return parseFloat(val,10).toFixed(2) });
 });
```

Comment: The code u provided,  Its not working for me.. Part 2 is working but i have already done that only. The code i have written is working but only i need is, it should also allow negative values. Could u please help me in that :)

Comment: You can use the regex `var regex = /^-?\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;`